# I have a weird CSS style tag in my browser on some sites

Tags: html, css, localhost, styles

Hi guys I have a problem with some sites from my university and at my localhost. We started with web developement and learned html and css. The thing is I found a very weird CSS Tag in my Head with very weird and scammy looking refs. I looked at some of the links and maybe it sounds weird but some links are P*rn sites or some tracker sites as it seems from the names. I only have this problem on the sites my Uni gives me where my tasks are and at my localhost when I work with Spring and Intellij on my own Website. I am a little scared tbh. I run the Opera GX browser. I tried Firefox to check if the style tag was there aswell but there wasnt. The tag starts like this : : "some weird root: tags and hrefs" Anyone has a clue whats going on?

I also checked at my laptop since it runs opera GX aswell and the weird style tag is there aswell. I didnt find any help when I checked in google for a solution.

Comment: You said "some sites".  Does it only happen on insecure http (as opposed to https) sites?  It only happens in one browser apparently so I'd guess you have some malware in that browser.  I'd uninstall it if I were you and run a virus scan.

Comment: I already did but it didnt work

Comment: Please answer the question I asked (http vs https) so we can help you.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Just look at the URL in your browser, eg it's https:// for stackoverflow.  My hunch is that if it starts with http:// it happens but if it starts with https:// (i.e .secure) it doesn't happen.   Please check and confirm.

Comment: Ah when I open my worksheet site it says "Not Safe"/insecure I guess since I have it in german

Comment: Yeah OK, so Not safe" means "http" (you won't get that warning on localhost because localhost is special).  So that suggests something is inserting content into non-secure sites.

Comment: for the site it says http

Comment: Do you have any extensions added to the Opera browser?  If so, try disabling them.  They may have malware.

Comment: I only have the integrated adblocker from Opera Gx

Comment: Hmm I just deactivated the own Adblocker from Opera Gx, now the weird links inside of that style tag are gone, but thr tag is still there: <style type="text/css"></style>

Comment: Not sure I can help any more, other than "avoid Opera".  I assume you downloaded it from the standard place.  If it was any other site, they may have inserted malware.  Here is a similar post BTW https://www.reddit.com/r/operabrowser/comments/cytt9e/is_opera_gx_downloading_virus/

Comment: Okay, I am still thankful for ur help sir, I try my best to fix this issue, but if you maybe do suddenly know how to fix the problem I would be very happy!

Comment: Btw I fixed it, the cause was the integrated adblocker for Opera GX, I was pretty shocked at first because of that since its recommended from Opera itself. Im very confused, does that mean Opera GX supports malware? I installed another Adblocker (Adblock plus) and everything is fine now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sometimes your browser extension forcefully append html/css tag in your browsing site.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your browser extension forcefully append html/css tag in your browsing site. So try to remove unwanted extension/add-ons from your browser.
Or clean unistall your browser and install a fresh one.

Comment: Already did, I removed the adblocker and it worked again, thanks

Comment: Good to hear this.

Answer (score -1):

If you saw anything similar to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

This is a cascade style sheet file pertaining to your site and can be loaded directly from a website

If you saw anything similar to this:

```
<style>
h1 {

  color: orange;
```

}

All coding in this section is styling directly embedded into your website via your html file.